# React Module Parse Fails When Adding Images

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've read all other threads on this subject and cannot find the solution to my problem. I'm getting a webpack "module parse failed" error specifically when I try to add images (of any file type) to my React project. Here is the specific error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
errors @ client:159
```

I've tried editing my webpack.config file based on what I've read in other threads, but nothing works. Does anyone have any suggestions? See below for code snippets, and [here's a link](https://github.com/mickey-vershbow/books_frontend2.git) to the project on Github.

WEBPACK.CONFIG.JS

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env) => {
  const { production } = env ? env : { production: false };

  const main = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./src/index.jsx",
    output: {
      filename: "bundle.js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.m?\js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
              plugins: [
                ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
                "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: "My React Project",
        template: "./src/index.html",
      }),
    ],
    output: {
      filename: "[name].bundle.js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all",
      },
    },
  };

  const dev = {
    output: {
      filename: "dev.js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dev"),
    },
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    devServer: {
      contentBase: "./dev",
      port: process.env.PORT,
    },
  };

  return production ? main : { ...main, ...dev };
};
```

**Again, this error is only triggered when I try to add images (.jpeg, .png, .svg) to my project**

Answer (score 1):

In all of your rules you've not defined any loader to handle any images (or any files), so when you import it it won't know what to do with it.

```
{
  test: /\.(ico|svg|png|jpg)$/,
  type: 'asset/resource',
}
```

If you're using webpack 5 you need to add that to your rules so that webpack knows what to to with images.  Using the above it will take your imports and copy them over to the output directory and map the URL to the source.

Alternatively can you use `file-loader`, `url-loader` or any similar loaders to load your files in webpack 4.